# popup balloon in JQuery

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-plugins

I used the following command to make a popup balloon each time mouse move on a div tag in a web page and I am trying to insert this command in any web page I am parsing so I append the command in the head as follows:

```
head.append("$('div').attr('onmouseover', 'balloon.showTooltip(event,You are hovering, I said click me! <a href=www.google.com>Click</a>)');");
```

where 
ballon is the object I defined it previously

But it does not work

Comment: zero upvotes cast as well....

Comment: You would have to provide more context to your question so we could understand what you are really trying to do.  What is "head"?  When you say it does not work, what do you mean?  Do you mean it doesn't insert into the DOM or do you mean the mouse over function doesn't work.  Have you looked for script errors?  What have you tried and what do you know so far.  Just saying: "But it does not work" gives us no information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides not understanding what the question really is, there are a lot of things wrong with this code.  The main issue I see is that the showTooltip function call is not legal javascript because the message is not a quoted string.  In addition, this is not a good way to use event handlers in jQuery.  Assuming that head is a jQuery object in your page (and not the head tag), try this:

```
head.append($("<div class='test'>").mouseover(function() {
    balloon.showTooltip(event, "You are hovering, I said click me! <a href='http://www.google.com'>Click</a>");
});
```

The other issue with this is that the `<div>` that you create and append to the page has no size so you can never get a mouseover event on it.  If you give it a finite size, it can work.  You can see that here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Y6LGT/ where I give it a class name and use CSS to give it a size.